# Hybridauth login not working

Tags: 7, social-network, authentication-authorization

I am using [hybridauth](https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module for LinkedIn and twitter login. I have installed [twitter module](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIsNXVxeDMAhUHRo8KHQKhCp8QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Ftwitter&usg=AFQjCNEuacD6sWNER4Ehdq-58wdSlLecSA&sig2=S7NKpVQnfoUkWPYaimLg7g&bvm=bv.122129774,d.c2I) and twitter post module for posting node on twitter. After enabling twitter module Linkedin login via hybridauth not working, it shows a blank page. If I disable twitter module it works fine. Kindly guide me to resolve this.

Comment: **Installation** did you do step 1? `Download HybridAuth library and unpack it into "sites/all/libraries/hybridauth" folder`

Comment: yes I added hybridauth library and it works fine it twitter module is disabled.

Comment: Commented out the OAuthException class from the OAuth.php file and twitter login was working instantly. This file can be found at: sites/all/libraries/hybridauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth.php

Comment: @vgoradiya for linked in.

Comment: is twitter working for you?

Comment: which version of hybridauth library you used?

Comment: @vgoradiya I am using HybridAuth 2.4.2-dev library and I have commented this line class OAuthException extends Exception {... but not working.